# nested for lops in openmp

Tags: c, loops, openmp

What is the correct wat of parallelization to 3 nested for loops with openmp?
this way:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
   for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
    for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
      mresult[i][j]=mresult[i][j] + matrixa[i][k]*matrixb[k][j];
```

or this way

```
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
      mresult[i][j]=mresult[i][j] + matrixa[i][k]*matrixb[k][j];
```

Comment: Neither way is correct. The first one should be `#pragma omp parallel for private(j,k)`.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is strictly incorrect because there is a race condition. Also nesting `parallel` is generally a bad idea is it will typically spawn more threads than cores resulting in bad performance.

The first line is just fine if `SIZE` is large enough to expose enough parallel work. Generally, parallelizing the outermost loop is best due to more work for the same parallelization overhead. If the outermost loop did not have enough parallelism, one could consider adding `collapse(2)` - which would is the correct way to parallelize loops albeit not necessary in this case.

That all said, if you want a performance matrix multiplication, use a library as tim18 indicated. Getting optimal efficiency from matrix multiplication is extremely complex and way beyond the scope of this answer.

As Z-Boson points out, your first version is also incorrect because the inner loop variables are shared by default. You can mark them `private(j,k)` or better yet just define them in the loop which is much clearer anyway:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
  for (int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
    for (int k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
```

Comment: Conforming to C99 style (it's been over 15 years) may help with compiler optimization of the inner loops when those are not set as threaded parallel.  OpenMP makes parallel for implies private for the immediately following for() parameter, but that appears to be a holdover from C89.

Answer (score -1):

Neither of those would approach the efficiency of threaded implementations of netlib gemm. No doubt this has been discussed many times in more detail.  If your case is large enough to be interested in parallelism, barring some specialized architecture like nvidia, the outer loop will be sufficiently large to keep each thread busy on nearly equal chunks of contiguous memory, and you will not want to prevent your compiler from applying single thread optimization on the inner loops.